# Rolling Distinct Counts

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17099743/349468) regarding how to get a rolling count of distinct users using SQL, but I also have Hadoop at my disposal and now I'm wondering if this analysis isn't better suited for Hadoop. Unfortunately, I'm new to Hadoop so beyond getting the data loaded and the most basic MapReduce jobs I'm ignorant on how to approach this. Assuming this is a good candidate for Hadoop, what is the best approach to take?

Comment: Roughly how many records are you expecting to process, how many distinct users, over what duration? - M/R may be overkill (and significantly less efficient than a SQL query) if the volumes don't warrant using it.

Comment: It's definitely not a large dataset (couple hundred distinct users a day), but the problem is we haven't been able to figure out a way to approach this using SQL while keeping the query performant without running it a day at a time.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to model this in map reduce:

1. M/R Job 1:

   - Mapper: extract and output the USER_ID (output key) and date portion from the CONNECT_TS (output value).
   - Reducer: For each USER_ID group (output key), output the minimum date observed (output value)
2. M/R Job 2:

   - Mapper: from the previous job output, swap the key / value pairs (DATE as output key, USER_ID as value)
   - Reducer (single): for each input key (date), count the number of users (value), output this number along with an accumulated running total.

In Pig, everything except keeping the running total could be done using the following script:

```
A = LOAD '/home/cswhite/data.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (SESSION, USER_ID, TIMESTAMP);
B = foreach A GENERATE USER_ID, SUBSTRING(TIMESTAMP, 0, 10) AS DATE;
BF = filter B by DATE > '2013-01-01';
C = group BF by USER_ID;
D = foreach C {
  sorted = order BF by DATE;
  earliest = limit sorted 1;
  generate group, flatten(earliest);
}
E = foreach D generate group as USER_ID, earliest::DATE as DATE;
F = group E by DATE;
G = foreach F generate group as DATE, COUNT(E) as USERS_CNT;
H = group G by ALL
I = foreach G generate SUM(G.USERS_CNT) as TOTAL_USERS;
```

So for the following tab separated input data:

```
1   99  2013-01-01 2:23:33
2   101 2013-01-01 2:23:55
3   104 2013-01-01 2:24:41
4   101 2013-01-01 2:24:43
5   101 2013-01-02 2:25:01
6   102 2013-01-02 2:26:01
7   99  2013-01-03 2:27:01
8   92  2013-01-04 2:28:01
9   234 2013-01-05 2:29:01
```

The alias `G` is as follows:

```
(2013-01-01,3)
(2013-01-02,1)
(2013-01-04,1)
(2013-01-05,1)
```

And alias 'I' is:

```
(5)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot simply aggregate it into a running total, which is the issue we are having. If the same user uses the app across multiple days they should only be counted once in the running total.

Comment: Why not? The above only counts the user 101 on the 2013-01-01 day, not the 2013-01-02 day

Comment: This is what the order and limit statements are doing in the foreach C portion

Comment: I guess I was confused when you said "easily calculate the running totals". I'll give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: This definitely isn't doing something right. First, the counts are way off from the distinct counts from the DB. Second, as I suspected it's only giving distinct counts of users by day, not for the rolling 45 day period.

Comment: The 'last 45 days' can be fixed using a filter between B and C. As for the total number for the last 45 days (rather than a rolling accumulated total for each day), that's just another statement operating on G (i'll update to show both).